# Nest JSON from array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to achieve something which seemed very basic but is getting me mad over the last days.

I have a simple array : `["a","b","c","d","e"]` and I want to turn it into a nested JSON like this:

```
{"a":{"b":{"c":{"d":{"e":""}}}}}
```

Looping over it, I ran in problems like "how do you save the last key to set it afterwards without erasing it" and so on.

Does anyone has an idea?

Comment: Why are you doing this? Just for fun?

Comment: How will {"a":{"b":{"c":{"d":{"e":""}}}}} help you?

Comment: I have to build a jade block from a JSON which I have to build from an array ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might have had problems because you were looping in the wrong direction. Try to build the object from inside-out:

```
array.reduceRight(function(v, key) {
    var o = {};
    o[key] = v;
    return o;
}, "")
```

or, with a loop:

```
var val = "";
for (var i=array.length; i--; )
    var o = {};
    o[array[i]] = val;
    val = o;
}
return val;
```

Comment: Just what I needed! Never heard of that reduceRight method, very useful, thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it, recursively:

```
function convertToNestedObject(arr) {
    var result = {};

    if (arr.length === 1) {
        result[arr[0]] = '';
    } else {
        result[arr[0]] = convertToNestedObject(arr.slice(1, arr.length));
    }

    return result;
}
```

You could pass the start index in to the function instead of using `slice` and creating copies of the array:

```
function convertToNestedObject(arr, startIndex) {
    var result = {};


    if (arr.length - startIndex === 1) {
        result[arr[startIndex]] = '';
    } else {
        result[arr[startIndex]] = convertToNestedObject(arr, startIndex + 1);
    }

    return result;
}
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/jwcxfaeb/1/

Comment: You should make the base case for `arr.length == 0`

Comment: @Bergi: Not sure about that, if `arr.length` is `0`, then accessing the element at `arr[0]` will return `undefined`. Unless you meant changing the base case entirely

Comment: Yes, I mean changing the base case entirely so that there is no similarity to the recursive case at all - simplifying the whole function.

Comment: @Bergi: Okay, I think you're saying make the base case `if (arr.length === 0) { return ''; } else { // recursive case }`. Is that correct? If so, I don't see how it simplifies things that much. In any case, an iterative approach is much better for this problem anyway.

Comment: Yes, exactly. It removes a bit of code duplication, and - more relevant - makes the function work with an empty array.

Comment: @Bergi: That is very true about working with an empty array. Thanks for the input

Answer (score 0):

Put current element as key and empty object (`{}`) as value. Continue with newly inserted empty object.

```
function toNested(arr){
    var nested = {};
    var temp = nested;

    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        temp[arr[i]] = {};
        temp = temp[arr[i]];
    }

    return nested;
}
```